# Including link slice from Fireworks using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Javascript to put images from Fireworks into my HTML page in a "ghost div". However, the Appointment bookings button sliced via Fireworks is not included. How would I include the link slice for the button while still getting the image effect?

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.men').click (function() { 
        var image = ('<img src="images/deal_men.fw.png" width="700px" height="500px" alt="Deals" />')
        $('.deal_content').html(image).hide().fadeToggle('slow');   
    });
    $('.teen').click (function() { 
        var image = ('<img src="images/deal_teen.fw.png" width="700px" height="500px" alt="Deals" />')
        $('.deal_content').html(image).hide().fadeToggle('slow');   
    });
    $('.couple').click (function() { 
        var image = ('<img src="images/deal_couples.fw.png" width="700px" height="500px" alt="Deals" />')
        $('.deal_content').html(image).hide().fadeToggle('slow');   
    });
});
```